# Ubuntu NFS client hangs while writing large file

Tags: nfs

I am hosting an NFS server on my Synology NAS. It is configured via the in-built NFS server under File Services. The configuration options are somewhat limited and I have set 32kb read/write packet size and max NFS version is 4.1.

The /etc/exports entry is:

```
/volume1/NAS_Andrew 192.168.0.0/24(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,insecure,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
```

My ubuntu client has the following fstab entry:

```
192.168.0.219:/volume1/NAS_Andrew /mnt/nas nfs nofail,nconnect=16,rsize=32000,wsize=32000,hard 0 0
```

This resolves to the following entry in /proc/mounts when mounted:

```
192.168.0.219:/volume1/NAS_Andrew /mnt/nas nfs4 rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=32000,wsize=32000,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,nconnect=16,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.0.220,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.0.219 0 0
```

The problem is that when I am writing a large file to the NFS mount, all other filesystem operations within the mount hang.

For example, if I run the following in terminal 1:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/nas/testfile bs=16k count=128k
```

and then run `ls -la` in terminal 2; the `ls` process hangs until the `dd` write is complete.

I believe the issue is limited to the local NFS client because if I run the same `ls -la` on another server that also has the NFS share mounted - it runs without any hang or issue.

I'm hoping that someone can shed some light as to why the write operation is blocking.
I tried setting `nconnect=16` in an effort to increase the tcp connections and allow more than one operation - however this did not work and I suspect `nconnect` may be limited to cases where multiple network interfaces are available.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Any input is greatly appreciated.